# Sharing cached image using Glide looses extension type

Tags: android, image, caching, android-glide

I'm trying to share cached images using Glide. I'm able to share the file, but it loses the extension (mimeType) and it's shared as a binary file with `.0` extension.

```
  glide
  .asBitmap()
  .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
  .load("url")
```

Here is how I'm getting the file from the cache

```
fun getFileFromCache(url: String) = glide.downloadOnly().load("url")
```

Any idea or suggestion, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the reason you are getting `.0` extension is that `downloadOnly` gives you the File from SOURCE cache and DiskLruCache has versioning built-in. Depending on what you do with pickedPhotoPath I suggest copying (do not rename) it to its final place (you can get the content type or file name from the photoUri), or keeping it in memory via:
you can copy (do not rename) it to its final place (you can get the content type or file name from the photoUri), or keeping it in memory. here's the code that can save the image (it's in java but I'm sure you could convert it to kotlin) :

```
public static synchronized void saveImage(final Context context, final String imageUrl) {
    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
         .load(imageUrl)
         .downloadOnly(new SimpleTarget<File>() {
             @Override public void onResourceReady(File src, GlideAnimation<? super File> glideAnimation) {
                 new GalleryFileSaver(context, imageUrl, src).execute();
             }
         });
}

private static class GalleryFileSaver extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String imageUrl;
    private final File src;
    public GalleryFileSaver(Context context, String imageUrl, File src) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.src = src;
    }

    @Override protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            dst = new File(getGalleryFolder(), getTargetFileName());
            copy(new FileInputStream(src), new FileOutputStream(dst));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            dst = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dst;
    }
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(File dst) {
        String message = dst != null? "Saved file to " + dst : "Failed to save file from " + src;
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 16];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            try { in.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) { }
            try { out.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) { }
        }
    }
    private String getTargetFileName() throws IOException {
        Random random = new Random();
        String ext = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(imageUrl);
        String name = String.valueOf(random.nextInt()) + ".jpg";
        Log.w("saeed", name);
        return name;
    }
    private File getGalleryFolder() throws IOException {
        File gallery = new File(APP_GALLERY_IMAGE_PATH);
        if (!gallery.mkdirs() && (!gallery.exists() || !gallery.isDirectory())) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid gallery path: " + gallery);
        }
        return gallery;
    }
}
```